# How to get json request in spring controller?

Tags: json, spring

Here is the code of my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST )
public ModelAndView  saveArticle(@ModelAttribute Article article, BindingResult result) {
                     System.out.println("inside controller"+article.getArticleName()+"  "+article.getArticleDesc());
                     int a=articleService.addArticle(article);

                    if(a==1)
                    {
                        return new ModelAndView("success");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return new ModelAndView( "error");
                    }
                     /*else if(a==0){
                         return new ModelAndView("error");
                     }*/
                    //return new ModelAndView("redirect:/articles.html");
        }
```

How to get the articleName and desc sent by json format and then convert them to java object?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `@RequestBody` annotation.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html

You may also include [jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) to serialize/deserialize the objects.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST )
public ModelAndView  saveArticle(@RequestBody Article article, BindingResult result) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: How to include jackson in spring dynamic web project?

Comment: Download the jars you need and put them in your WEB-INF/lib directory. An easy way to find the jars is through the [mvnrepository](http://mvnrepository.com) website. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core

Comment: I am getting http status 415 when using @RequestBody.I configured dispatcherservlet as follows.                                               <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

Comment: Make sure the XMLHttpRequest has the `Content-Type: application/json` header set.

Comment: can you please  tell me what are the things I need to change in my dispatcher Servlet?

Comment: Setting the header has nothing to do with the servlet. How are you sending the request?

Comment: I am using Post Man add on for sending REST request.So as you have already mentioned I added @RequestBody.Yoo  told me to install jackson .I added them in my build path as? well as lib.Now I need to create the bean  in dispatcher-servlet.xml for using jackson.So how can I do that?

Comment: I added the above jackson jars you mentioned but I amn getting exception as follows:                                                          org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonMessageConverter'

Comment: Please update your question with all the code and configuration you have now

Comment: My controller
:@RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public  @ResponseBody ModelAndView saveArticle(@RequestBody Article article) {
                     
                         int a=articleService.addArticle(article);
                         if(a==1)
                         {
                         return new ModelAndView("success");
                         }
                         else
                         {
                         return new ModelAndView("error"); 
                         }
                        
                         }

Comment: My dispatcherServlet:              <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
<property name="messageConverters">
  <list>
    <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
  </list>
</property>
</bean>

Comment: I have added jackson core,jackson mapper,jackson data bind in my class path.But still I am getting the error:org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper